# How to I convert genes/features of species A to orthologous genes for species B for cross species single cell RNA sequencing dataset integration

Tags: r, integration, bioinformatics, seurat, biomart

I am trying to do a cross-species single cell RNA sequencing integration using Seurat with a zebrafish dataset and a chick dataset. I have generated seurat objects for both. How can I use Ensemble ID (bioMart) to convert chick genes dataset to those of the zebrafish and apply this to the Seurat object for integration?

Comment: Do zebrafish and chick have a one-to-one ortholog genome? Else you will probably need to blast all your zebra genes unto the chick genome and pick the lowest E-score (or use some application that does this) for each gene. I doubt you can do it just based on EID

Comment: Thank you for your reply, since I posted this I've found nearly 20,000 orthologous one2one genes between them of them using biomaRt, I'm just still having issues reassigning features.